# Gitolite: Clone gitolite-admin successfully but warns of "key_read" failure

Tags: gitolite

I've installed gitolite3 on my git server and have setup gitolite with my public key. I can clone the gitolite-admin repo successfully but on clone, pull, push, anything, the command is executed but always displays the following message twice:

```
key_read: uudecode <public key> failed
```

What's causing this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

That can mean one of the public ssh key is incomplete or split into two lines instead of one.

Check also the `~/.ssh/known_host` on the user client side: if it has no empty line at the end, that could cause the error message as well.
Or delete it entirely and validate the host with a `ssh -Tv git@yourGitoliteServer`.

Comment: I had multiple entries in my client's known_host file for the git server. Cleared them both out and re-cloned solved my problem. TY!